# where should I put RestController in spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I used idea IDE to developed a Java springboot project follow a tutorial.
However, in the tutorial, there's a function shown below. I do not know where to put this function in me spring boot project.
The function:

```
package com.helloworld.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

/**
 * Created by fangxiao on 2017/3/24.
 */
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @RequestMapping("/helloworld")
    public String helloWorld() {
        return "helloworld";
    }
}
```

where should I put this function as for the below project structure?
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0DPO.png)

Answer (score 1):

Following your example, the Controller Class have a organization like this picture:

[image: spring-boot project organization]

I also created another packages that are frequentelly used in a spring-boot project

Answer (score 0):

Since your package is :

```
package com.helloworld.controller;
```

You can create folder structure inside java folder com -> helloworld -> controller and keep the code (Controller.java class) inside.

Answer (score 0):

Create a package under src/main/java like com.abc.rest and create RestController class
:Here is the sample code and to access this api use url like : localhost:8080/test/headers

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class Rest {
    
    @GetMapping("/headers")
    public String listAllHeaders(@RequestHeader Map<String, String> headers) {
        headers.forEach((key, value) -> {
            System.out.println(String.format("Header '%s' = %s", key, value));
        });
     return "success";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For learning purpose is good to do it manually, but if you want to skip it, you can create the class shown above in the `src/main/java` and IntelliJ will dectect and offer to relocate it to the proper package.

Comment: Maybe mention the correct folder in this case is src/main/java + <package>, therefore in this case src/main/java/com/helloworld/controller

Answer (score 0):

Create your package `com.project.controller` under

> D:\Bill\java\test\src\main\java

directory